# How to prove this using the epsilon delta definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} f(h+a)$

The above seemingly obvious result is what I want to prove.

My idea was to "set" $x$ to be equal to $h+a$ and then prove using the epsilon delta definition that $\lim_{h \to 0} h+a=a$ or that $\lim_{h \to 0} x=a$. This would (i think) mean that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=a$ since $x=h+a$ and ${h \to 0}$ implies that ${x \to a}$.

I didn't like it because we somehow had to "set" $x$ equal to $h+a$ in the beginning. I wonder if there is a better way to prove it.

Comment: Can't do that unless you know f is continous.  Use the definition directly.

Comment: @fleablood Could you show me how to?

Comment: I don't know how to format, so I'll write limit of f at a, where you would write the limit of f as x -->a. The so-called fog theorem says that if the limit of g at b  = L, then the limit of fog at b is f (L) provided f is continuous at L. In your case you are taking g(x)=x+a and b=0, and you have to know that f is continuous at L=g(0)=a. If you know this, then by the fog theorem the limit at 0 of fog(x)=f(x+a)=f(limit of g at 0) =f(a)=limit of f at a. My hunch is that if you can prove what you want, you can prove the fog theorem itself. by replacing x+a with g(x). In short get rid of h.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f (x)=c $ (assuming limit exists).  Let $\epsilon >0$.  Then there exists a $\delta >0$ so that $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f (x)-c|<\epsilon$.  Then $|h-0|=|(h+a)-a|<\delta \implies |f (h+a)-c|<\epsilon $.

So $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f (h+a)=c $.

Most do same thing for when limit doesn't exist.

====

I see by your comment you didn't understand this

Definition:  $\lim_{w\rightarrow a} f(w) = c$ means the for any value $\epsilon 0$ there exist a $\delta >0$ so that the following is true:  If $|w - a| < \delta$ or in other words if $w \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$ then $|f(w) - c| < \epsilon$ or in other words $f(w) \in (c-\epsilon, c + \epsilon)$.

Now $w \in (a-\delta, a+ \delta) \iff w-a \in (0 -\delta, 0+ \delta)$.

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = c$ means for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta$ so that $a-x \in (0-\delta, 0+\delta) \implies f(x)=f((x-a) + a) \in (c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon)$.

And that is the definition of $\lim_{x - a \rightarrow 0}f((x-a) +a) = c$. Now we can just relabel $x - a$ as $h$ where $h = x - a$.  So $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(h + a) = c = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$.

Comment: I know its a little late now, but could you just tell me how you implied that $h$ approaches 0?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  h "approaches 0 for the same reason x "approaches" a.   I select values so that it does.  For the every interval $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ there is an interval equal in length $(-\delta, \delta)$ and for every $h \in (-\delta, \delta)$ we know $a+ h \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$.  So $|h| < \delta \iff |h - 0| < \delta \iff |(a+h) - a| < \delta$.  We know that if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - c| < \epsilon$.  So if $|h-0| < 0$ then $|(a+h) -a | < \delta$ so $|f(a+h) - c| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Can you believe $\lim_{w \rightarrow a}f(w) = \lim_{v \rightarrow (a-k)}f(v+k)$?  If not can you believe that if $w \rightarrow a$ then $w - k \rightarrow a - k$ and therefore if as $w-k \rightarrow a-k$ then $w \rightarrow a$ we have $w \rightarrow a$ so $f(w) \rightarrow \lim_{w\rightarrow a} f(w) = \lim_{w-k \rightarrow a-k} f((w-k) + k)$?

Answer (score 1):

With $a,L\in\mathbb R, $and $f:I\to\mathbb R,\;$we have

> $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L \implies$

$\forall \epsilon>0\;\;\exists \alpha>0\;\;\forall x\in I $

$a-\alpha<x<a+\alpha \;\;\implies  |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

$\implies$

$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\;\exists \alpha>0;
\forall h>0\;\;|h|<\alpha$

$\implies  a-\alpha<a+h<a+\alpha $

$\implies |f(a+h)-L|<\epsilon $

> $\implies  \lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=L$

$\implies$

$\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists \alpha>0\;\forall x\in I a-\alpha<x<a+\alpha \implies |h|=|x-a|<\alpha \implies |f(a+x-a)-L|=|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

> $\implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L.$